# apache2-mod_fcgid-1.10-15 installed via rpm but not avaiable in apache

Tags: apache2, mod-fcgid

I have installed  apache2-mod_fcgid-1.10-15.rpm on a sles 10.2 with apache installed sin before.

rpm -i apache2-mod_fcgid-1.10-15.rpm givs no error.

The following moduelse are loaded. (is it there under a name that I missed?)

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 python_module (shared)
Syntax OK
selnc211:/tmp/a # httpd2 -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
selnc211:/tmp/a #
```

Comment: does your configuration contain a LoadModule line for the fcgi module? Maybe the config was not added because it was changed manually: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule

Comment: I actualy had the module in the correct catalog fpr several days but my there is something frong. In my  httpd.conf I have: LoadModule fcg_module /usr/lib/apache2/mod_fcgid.so . When restarting apatche i get: httpd2-prefork: Syntax error on line 217 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `fcg_module' in file /usr/lib/apache2/mod_fcgid.so: /usr/lib/apache2/mod_fcgid.so: undefined symbol: fcg_module. Name it fcg_module was something I made up myself. Was this wrong?

Comment: The "/usr/lib/apache2/mod_fcgid.so" must be an actual file. If you have a look into that directory where the other modules reside the one you are looking for should be there too (since you used an rpm to install).

Comment: Yes it is there, so are all oter files: # ls /usr/lib/apache2/mod_fcgid.so -ls
68 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 64472 Nov 26  2006 /usr/lib/apache2/mod_fcgid.so . I now see that it has been there for many years. So my only need is to activate it. And the line I used gave the aboce error.